# How to accept TCP requests into Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tcp

How to accept TCP protocol into a Spring Boot application? `HTTP` works over `TCP` but I need to accept lower-level protocol.

Can anyone give me a route or hint on how to implement it?

Is it the same as for HTTP connection with `Controller`, `Service`, `Repository` architecture?

Comment: Well... are you using Cloud Foundry? This is not a Spring Boot question, the only thing Spring Boot in that link is a standard hello world Spring Boot web application with HTTPS enabled.

Comment: You know that HTTP runs on top of TCP, right?

Comment: @Gimby Yes, I use Spring Boot and the only reason Cloud Foundry in the question is because I cannot find anything related to Spring Boot and TCP.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, I know this. But I need to accept naked TCP.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi that is because a non-http tcp route is a Cloud Foundry feature... completely unrelated to Spring.

Comment: @Gimby If paraphrase your comment. Spring Boot doesn't support TCP protocols and I need to look at Cloud Foundry or alternative solutions, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your program using Socket programming by implementing CommandLineRunner interface of Spring Boot. Socket part of the program connect to a server using TCP and start accepting the request, then transform the binary message as per your required format and do the rest of the processing.

And if you want to create a server, then use ServerSocket in your program that will accept connections from client.

Answer (score 0):

you got OK with this command ???

$ cf create-route pcfdev-space tcp.local.pcfdev.io --random-port

Generaly with Spring boot: 
HTTP routes include a domain, an optional hostname, and an optional context path. cfapps.io, myapp.cfapps.io, and myapp.cfapps.io/products are all examples of HTTP routes. Apps should listen to the localhost port defined by the $PORT environment variable, which is 8080 on Diego. As an example, requests to myapp.cfapps.io would be routed to the app container at localhost:8080

Source : https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html